# Rewrite an integral and compute a Riemann sum numerically

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, numerical-methods, riemann-integration

I have the following integral:
$$I=\int^{\pi/4}_{0}\cos(x)\ln(x)dx$$
And I want to rewrite it in the following form: $I=a-J$, where $J=\int^{\pi/4}_{0}h(x)dx$.

$a \in R$ is a constant the function $h(x)$ is continuous and bounded around zero. I want to find $a$ and $h(x)$.

Now when I have $I$, I want to compute $I$ numerically (in R-studio) by applying the Riemann rule to $J$, by using 100 nodes for the computation of $J$.

I'm not sure how to start, any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Writing $\cos x = 1 - (1 - \cos x)$ is a good start.

Comment: Notice that $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\sin^2\frac{x}{2}\log x=0$ since $\lim_{x\to 0^+}x\log x = 0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have what you need already, so I'll post an answer for completeness sake. Credits to Daniel Fischer

$$ \int_0^{\pi/4} \cos x \ln x\ dx = \int_0^{\pi/4} \left(1-2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\right)\ln x \ dx = \frac{\pi}{4}\left(\ln \frac{\pi}{4} - 1\right) - \int_0^{\pi/4}2\sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\ln x\ dx $$

and also
$$ \lim_{x\to 0}\ \sin^2 \frac{x}{2}\ln x = 0 $$

Comment: Makes sense! Do you know how I could compute I numerically? what does using 100 nodes mean?

Comment: I assumed you already knew what it meant when you posted the question. Numerical methods aren't my forte. Feel free to post another question though, or look up some documentation